# how to manage text message time stamp for chat app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chatbot

I'm actually building a chat app and using react and when I send a message it takes my local time and saved it to the database and using socket io library the receiver will get the message the problem is first it will work fine if both sender and receiver have the same timezone but if they have different timezones it will say  just now for the sender  but for the receiver 5 hours ago  how to fix that is there any library or is a way to fix the code

and also I'm using timeago.js to format the timestamp like, just now,4 hours ago...

//sender side

```
const socketMessage = {
        _id:uuid(),
        conversationId,
        senderId: user?._id,
        textMessage,
        username: currentChat.username,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        senderUsername: user?.username,
    };
     socket.emit("sendMessage", socketMessage);
```

//receiver side

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    socket?.on("getMessage", (data) => {
        if (mounted) {
            setArrivalMessage({
                _id: data._id,
                conversationId: data.conversationId,
                senderId: data.senderId,
                textMessage: data?.textMessage,
                createdAt: data.createdAt,

            });
        }
    });

    return () => {
        mounted = false;
    };
}, [socket]);
```

Comment: the problem is related to the timezone difference. Server doesn't have any information about the client's timezone. What you can do. Convert time in the client's side to UTC and send UTC time to backend. Discussion about the related issue in [timeago.js](https://github.com/hustcc/timeago.js/issues/122) site

Comment: Maybe its not a good solution: try to send timestamp as @Vigen mentioned, like: `new Date().getTime()` and in client side just create a new date like: `new Date(data.createdAt)`